# Default action button icons in Java

Tags: java, swing, icons

Is there a set of default action icons available in the Swing application framework?

For instance, instead of making a button that says "Save," I'd like the standard picture of a floppy disk without having to specify an image myself. For "Open", I'd like the standard picture of a file folder. It would be great if these adapted to the look and feel, but I'd take Swing defaults.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
new JButton(new ImageIcon(DEFAULT_OPEN_ICON));
```

I have found lots of resources about changing the *look and feel*, but nothing about icons either built into Java or dug out of the native system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Java Look and Feel Graphics Repository](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/repository-140393.html) has a few icons you might be able to use.

Comment: These look good.  It looks like I'm going to have to bundle graphics, and this is a good default.  Thanks!

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/repository-140393.html direct link, to avoid Oracles annoying policy against deep linking.

Answer (score 21):

The [javax.swing.UIManager#getIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) method provides access to several default system icons. The trick is knowing what `String` to provide. Here are a some examples:

```
UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directoryIcon");
UIManager.getIcon("FileView.fileIcon");
UIManager.getIcon("FileView.computerIcon");
UIManager.getIcon("FileView.hardDriveIcon");
UIManager.getIcon("FileView.floppyDriveIcon");

UIManager.getIcon("FileChooser.newFolderIcon");
UIManager.getIcon("FileChooser.upFolderIcon");
UIManager.getIcon("FileChooser.homeFolderIcon");
UIManager.getIcon("FileChooser.detailsViewIcon");
UIManager.getIcon("FileChooser.listViewIcon");
```

[Source](https://community.oracle.com/message/13439835#discussion-13484479) @ Oracle<sup>®</sup> Community Spaces. <sup>[*Original (cached)*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:I4eEkg-DEHUJ:https://www.java.net/node/674913+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)</sup>

Comment: a useful link [http://en-human-begin.blogspot.com/2007/11/javas-icons-by-default.html](http://en-human-begin.blogspot.com/2007/11/javas-icons-by-default.html)

Answer (score 8):

[`FileSystemView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) has some useful platform-dependent icons; [`FileBrowser`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692) is an example.

Addendum: The result depends on the platform and the parameter that is passed to `getSystemIcon()`. You might also search among the [*UIManager Defaults*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) by value type `Icon` for a given Look & Feel. I'd also browse various [open source icon sets](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_icon_sets). Because not all meanings are obvious, be sure to apply a tooltip and use familiar grouping.

Comment: I see that it's using file icons from the platform, but I don't see it using any icons for open, save, etc.  Am I just missing it?  e.g. It looks like the openFile button is just labeled "Open".  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No built in icons in the Java SDK, but they should be easy enough to find:

The Java™ Tutorials: [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Google Image search: "[*jquery ui button icons*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=jquery+ui+button+icons)"

Comment: @RayHulha: This answer is over two years older than [Leif](http://stackoverflow.com/users/52176/leif-gruenwoldt)'s. No one else suggested alternative icons.

Comment: The icons from Leif's answer existed in 2012 as well. Duffymo just didn't have his facts straight.