# Java default JFileChooser Icon Location

Tags: java, jfilechooser

When you use `JFileChooser` it has default folder and file icons, where are they? I want to get get their width and height params.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498506/java-howto-get-the-thumbnail-from-a-file)

Comment: That's not what i'm asking, The default icons that java uses. I want to open them in paint and modify them. I was wondering where they are on the drive?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26589183/838992) give what you're looking for? e.g. `UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directoryIcon").getIconHeight();`

Comment: BTW, I'm not the down voter, but my guess is that the question is down voted because it appears to be a request for off site resources (which is explicitly mentioned as off-topic in the "asking a question" FAQ), rather than programming - although I think that's contentious in this case.

Comment: @J Richard Snap Thank you! I didn't think it was off topic but if it bother's people i can remove it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directoryIcon").getIconHeight();
```

Answer by Richard Snape.